# The installation is missing the file\Sharepoint Assembly

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016

Good day! When you try to install updates for SharePoint 2016, It fails.  Is recorded in the log of the error:

> ERROR Failed to call GetTypes() d0aabc9e-f5f4-f088-047b-1a50b287a5e0;
>
> ERROR Exception: failed to load file or Assembly '
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" or one of their
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   d0aabc9e-f5f4-f088-047b-1a50b287a5e0;

How to install not accrue to the Assembly on the SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has recently been deleted AppFabric 1.1 and re-installed.

Checked path `C:\Windows\assembly\` and there is a `Microsoft file.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core 1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35`
Installer prerequisites shows that all the necessary components installed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was happening  is because  `AppFabric 1.1` (One of the SharePoint Prerequisites) was uninstalled.

Please check if Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core at `C:\Windows\assembly\gac_msil\Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35` exists.

If not, ran the prerequisites installer and found that the both `AppFabric 1.1` for Windows Server and CU1 were installed successfully.

Then run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard on the problematic server again.