# Restart the SharePoint site

Tags: 2013, 2016, 2019

When you try to reload the site (SharePoint-80) you get a message like the screenshot. How to fix?

Error: failed to write configuration file

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried run SharePoint Configuration Wizzard? Any errors here?

Comment: Yes, fails with type error:
One. Failed to call GetTypes()  d0aabc9e-f5f4-f088-047b-1a50b287a5e0;
Two. Could Not load file or Assembly Microsoft.The value of the application server.Caching.Client, version=1.0.0.0, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" or one of their dependencies; 
Three. One or more types failed to load;

Comment: have you done something with AppFabric? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257179/the-installation-is-missing-the-file-sharepoint-assembly?rq=1

Comment: by chance AppFabric was removed and re-installed

Comment: try to fix AppFabric probably

Comment: Вот как его исправить?